# ElasticSearch geo search

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, geospatial

So I've just started with elasticsearch and having a little trouble with geo searching.

I have this index:

```
"mappings" => [
    "draw_point" => [
        "properties" => [
            "name" => ["type" => "string"],
            "type" => ["type" => "string"],
            "location" => ["type" => "geo_point"]
        ]
    ]
]
```

And inserted some data:

```
{
    "_index": "draw_points",
    "_type": "draw_point",
    "_id": "AVYnDfCLzY04KlPeX37B",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Tower",
      "type": "Water",
      "location": {
        "lat": 48.8584,
        "lon": 2.2945
      }
    }
  }
```

however when I use the following to geo search, I always get everything back:

```
"query": {
   "filtered": {
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
            "distance": "1km",
            "location": {
            "lat": 51.5074,
            "lon": 0.1278
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which client are you using? Are you sending your query with GET or POST?

Comment: I'm using this composer package, which it seems its just a wrapper over the official php client.

Comment: Are you sending your query with GET or POST?

Comment: Im using the ->search() function of the php client, so its using GET internally from the looks of the code.

Comment: Can you update your question with your client PHP code and how you send your query?